# Using boot::boot() function with grouped variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics-bootstrap

This is a question both about using the boot() function with grouped variables, but also about passing multiple columns of data into boot. Almost all examples of the boot() function seem to pass a single column of data to calculate a simple bootstrap of the mean.

My specific analysis is trying to use the stats::weighted.mean(x,w) function which takes a vector 'x' of values to calculate the mean and a second vector 'w' for weights. The main point is that I need two inputs into this function - and I'm hoping the solution will generalize to any function that takes multiple arguments.

I'm also looking for a solution to use this weighted.means function in a dplyr style workflow with group_by() variables. If the answer is that *"it can't be done with dplyr"*, that's fine, I'm just trying to figure it out.

Below I simulate a dataset with three groups (A,B,C) that each have different ranges of counts. I also attempt to come up with a function "my.function" that will be used to bootstrap the weighted average. Here might be my first mistake: is this how I would set up a function to pass in the 'count' and 'weight' columns of data into each bootstrapped sample? Is there some other way to index the data?

Inside the summarise() call, I reference the original data with "."  - Possibly another mistake?

The end result shows that I was able to achieve appropriately grouped calculations using mean() and weighted.mean(), but the calls for confidence intervals using boot() have instead calculated the 95% confidence interval around the global mean of the dataset.

Suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Why is the boot() function referencing the entire dataset and not the grouped subsets?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(boot)


set.seed(20)

sample.data = data.frame(letter = rep(c('A','B','C'),each = 50) %>% as.factor(),
                         counts = c(runif(50,10,30), runif(50,40,60), runif(50,60,100)),
                         weights = sample(10,150, replace = TRUE))



##Define function to bootstrap
  ##I'm using stats::weighted.mean() which needs to take in two arguments

##############
my.function = function(data,index){

  d = data[index,]  #create bootstrap sample of all columns of original data?
  return(weighted.mean(d$counts, d$weights))  #calculate weighted mean using 'counts' and 'weights' columns
  
}

##############

## group by 'letter' and calculate weighted mean, and upper/lower 95% CI limits

## I pass data to boot using "." thinking that this would only pass each grouped subset of data 
  ##(e.g., only letter "A") to boot, but instead it seems to pass the entire dataset. 

sample.data %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(counts),
            wtd.avg = weighted.mean(counts, weights),
            CI.LL = boot.ci(boot(., my.function, R = 100), type = "basic")$basic[4],
            CI.UL = boot.ci(boot(., my.function, R = 100), type = "basic")$basic[5])
```

[image: summarize results]

And below I've calculated a rough estimate of 95% confidence intervals around the global mean to show that this is what was going on with boot() in my summarise() call above

```
#Here is a rough 95% confidence interval estimate as +/-  1.96* Standard Error


mean(sample.data$counts) + c(-1,1) * 1.96 * sd(sample.data$counts)/sqrt(length(sample.data[,1]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following base R solution solves the problem of bootstrapping by groups. Note that `boot::boot` is only called once.

```
library(boot)

sp <- split(sample.data, sample.data$letter)
y <- lapply(sp, function(x){
  wtd.avg <- weighted.mean(x$counts, x$weights)
  basic <- boot.ci(boot(x, my.function, R = 100), type = "basic")$basic
  CI.LL <- basic[4]
  CI.UL <- basic[5]
  data.frame(wtd.avg, CI.LL, CI.UL)
})

do.call(rbind, y)
#   wtd.avg    CI.LL    CI.UL
#A 19.49044 17.77139 21.16161
#B 50.49048 48.79029 52.55376
#C 82.36993 78.80352 87.51872
```

Final clean-up:

```
rm(sp)
```

---

A `dplyr` solution could be the following. It also calls `map_dfr` from package `purrr`.

```
library(boot)
library(dplyr)

sample.data %>%
  group_split(letter) %>% 
  purrr::map_dfr(
    function(x){
      wtd.avg <- weighted.mean(x$counts, x$weights)
      basic <- boot.ci(boot(x, my.function, R = 100), type = "basic")$basic
      CI.LL <- basic[4]
      CI.UL <- basic[5]
      data.frame(wtd.avg, CI.LL, CI.UL)
    }
  )
#   wtd.avg    CI.LL    CI.UL
#1 19.49044 17.77139 21.16161
#2 50.49048 48.79029 52.55376
#3 82.36993 78.80352 87.51872
```